# Settext causing text to flicker irratically

Tags: java, android, arduino, settext

I'm making an app which establishes USB communication between an Arduino UNO R3 and an android tablet. Arduino board is sending data correctly and it is even being received by tablet correctly and when tried to display, the text does get printed but with a rather continuous flicker.

```
class MyThread extends Thread
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        mCallback = new UsbSerialInterface.UsbReadCallback()
        { //Defining a Callback which triggers whenever data is read.
            @Override
            public void onReceivedData(byte[] arg0) //data received in bytes
            {
                String data = null;

                try
                {

                    data = new String(arg0, "UTF-8");
                    handler.post(new newthread(data));                            

                }
                catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
class newthread implements Runnable
{
    String str1;        

    public newthread(String STR1)
    {            
        str1 = STR1;
    }
    @Override
    public void run()
    {

        DoseRateDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.DoseRateDisplay);
        if(str1.contains("L"))
        { tv6.append("Health OK"); }
        else
        {
           DoseRateDisplay.settext(str1);
        }
    }
}
```

I think the reason for flicker can be that the data is incoming too fast. Using Thread.sleep does not help. What can be the possible solution to this problem ? Also, using append instead of settext doesn't cause any flickering problems, but then data gets appended to textview.

Comment: Does the data change rapidly? If not, you could check if the `TextView` already has this text and do not set it again.

Comment: It's not about change in data. I tried sending a constant number from Arduino, even that flickers.

Comment: BTW, can you please tell how do you read the value of textview already printed...

Comment: textView.getText().toString();  For your problem have you considered changing the text view text based on a value received by Arduino? So it'll just update the text view if the value is different, not every time a value is received.

Comment: You say that you think the reason could be that values are coming in too fast. Have you tried only updating the TextView let's say once per 10 or 100 values?

Answer (score 0):

From my comment: try to check if the text received and the text already in the `TextView` are equal:

```
if(!DoseRateDisplay.getText().toString().equals(str1)) {
    DoseRateDisplay.settext(str1);
}
```

Comment: Logically, the if condition should be inverted. Also, it is still not working and flickering even then.

Comment: Yes of course, you are right. Have you tested (debugged) it? How often does it go into the statement? Everytime?

Comment: Yes, I did. There wasn't much difference before and after. I think the if condition gets true every time, i.e., the strings are always different.