# Large data overlows when trying to send from Arduino to Android

Tags: java, android, arduino, byte

I'm trying to send data in the form of numbers from my Arduino UNO R3 to Android tablet. I'm sending the number in the form of bytes and is being sent correctly from the Arduino side as was confirmed from the serial monitor in Arduino IDE. But on the receiving end, the data type makes it incompatible to support large numbers and the data overflows. Byte data type has the range from -128 to 127. So when I try to send a number greater than 127, say 200, the display shows -56. In fact, it displays bigger number in cycles of 256 characters. First it displays correctly upto 127, then it negates to -127, keeps on increasing all the way to 0 and continues increasing from 0 again.

```
class MyThread extends Thread
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        int x;
        String btstring;

        final ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(2);  //LINE1
        UsbRequest request = new UsbRequest();
        request.initialize(usbDeviceConnection, endpointIn);

        while (true)
        {

            request.queue(buffer, 1);  //LINE2

            if (usbDeviceConnection.requestWait() == request && DRD==true)
            {
                try
                {
                    x=buffer.get(0);
                    btstring = Integer.toString(x);

                    handler.post(new newthread(btstring));
                    //Thread.sleep(100);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class newthread implements Runnable
{
    String str0;

    public newthread(String STR0)
    {
        str0 = STR0;
    }
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
       if(str0!="0")  //to avoid blinking to zero value.
       {
           DoseRateDisplay.setText(str0);
       } 
    }
}
```

Here is the Arduino code just for reference:

```
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  Serial.write(200);
  delay(500);
}
```

What I believe is that **the two lines marked as LINE1 and LINE2 in the code** may be responsible for this shortage of space for the incoming data. I even tried changing their values, but to no avail. What can be done so as to incorporate data which is greater than 127? Any different style of data handling will also do.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use library to deal with receiving messages instead of trying to code serial port handling by yourself. Try this piece of code which I took from https://github.com/felHR85/SerialPortExample/blob/master/example/src/main/java/com/felhr/serialportexample/UsbService.java

```
private UsbSerialInterface.UsbReadCallback mCallback = new UsbSerialInterface.UsbReadCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onReceivedData(byte[] arg0) {
        try {
            String data = new String(arg0, "UTF-8");
            if (mHandler != null)
                mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_FROM_SERIAL_PORT, data).sendToTarget();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you explain what this line is actually doing:  mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_FROM_SERIAL_PORT, data).sendToTarget();

Comment: Look at the github project I linked. This line is handling recieved data parsing them into String and sends through BroadcasrReciever. In your case this message handling would use handler.post(new newthread(btstring));

Comment: Hey so the code you linked through GitHub has already been tried by me and that method has a different problem. It displays text correctly but with a continuous flicker. check this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38203558/settext-causing-text-to-flicker-irratically